# reference request: connection between automorphs of quadratic forms and real quadratic number field

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-forms

Let $Q$ be a primitive binary quadratic form. There is a relation between the generator of the group of integral automorphs and the fundamental unit of the corresponding real quadratic field. This is described in Remark 2.6 on page 6 of the following paper
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.0725.pdf
This is mentioned without a reference here... Can someone know a reference for this by any chance? Thank you.

Comment: This fact is quite clear. It is not suprising that you form become equivalent to hyperbolic one, if you add to you field the roots of the corresponding quadratic polynomial. Why do you need reference? I you are reading this article solve it as exercise, if you want to use this result in your own article, then cite this remark or say that it is obvious.